# Using Heroku Postgres database locally in a Rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku, database-migration

I have downloaded the database from an existing Heroku app onto my local machine.  The data I downloaded is in a single file; let's call it `herokuapp.db`. I also have Postgres installed and I can successfully create a new Postgres database and have my Rails app reference that. What I want to do is move the data I downloaded from Heroku into this database or create a new Postgres database using the downloaded data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -d [database_name] [herokuapp.db]`
see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/export-from-heroku-postgres for more information

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the same problem with a similar technique that Will suggested (thanks Will!).

```
$ heroku pgbackups:capture
$ curl -o latest.dump `heroku pgbackups:url`
$ pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -d [database_name] latest.dump
```

The database_name can be found in the development section of the database.yml file.

**EDIT**
I recently performed this task again with Postgres.app and the last command above did not work.  I was getting this error message:

```
pg_restore: connecting to database for restore
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] connection to database "[database_name]" failed: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
pg_restore: *** aborted because of error
```

Here is the updated command that worked:

```
$ pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U $USER -d [database_name] latest.dump
```